# echo get_post_meta of all post in a category to fill up a select field

Tags: categories, custom-field

I want to retrieve a specific post_meta of all posts contained in a specific category. I want to build a search form at the top of each category with a select field which would be filled up by the required post_meta of all the post contained in the category the user is currently in. Is this doable?
Maybe it's possible with a loop which would look like:

`For each post_meta called "City" in all posts contained in category 'X',
you must put it in <option value="City's name">City's name</option>`

So far, here is what I have been able to do.

```
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected">Please pick a city below...</option>
<option value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'City', true) ?>">
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'City', true) ?>
</option>
</select>
```

Not much, I know. Any help, please ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers!

I finally found what I wanted here : http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/custom-fields-search/
Here is the code :

```
<form name="search" action="" method="get">
<select name="City">
 <?php
  $metakey = 'city';
  $cities = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
  if ($cities) {
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
  echo "<option value=\"" . $city . "\">" . $city . "</option>";
    }
    }
 ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

This is a brilliant article and it helped me a lot! I hope it'll help others too.

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I  sounds like your doing this wrong. You do not typically query the post meta first in a hierarchical query since it will be much slower.  I don't really know how your structuring this by your question.

The logic should be -->query category--->query posts with meta value ( or tag or sub-category, don't forget these work to).

To do this you need to use `WP Query` http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

For example `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=4&meta_key=city' );`

If your using a lot of meta field values you should set `get_post_meta` to false or leave that parameter out to return an array ( your example has it set to true).

Comment: Please check the answer I posted, especially the link to the article "Enhancing WordPress Custom Fields with Search Filtering". That is what I meant to do. I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'category' => 3, 'meta_key' => 'City' );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
echo '<select>';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Please pick a city below...</option>';
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
    $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'City',true); ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $themeta; ?>"><?php echo $themeta; ?></option>
<?php endforeach;
echo '</select>';
?>
```

I didn't test it but it should work. It's getting all posts from a certain category along with a certain meta key.

Comment: I tested it but it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't even display the select field. Am I doing anything wrong?